# Java - Spark - Custom Comparator For Tuple2<String, String> Is Not Working

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, comparator

I have something like that:

```
JavaPairRDD<String,String> inputFiles = sc.wholeTextFiles(inputFolderPath, PARTITIONS);
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> intermediateInputFiles = JavaRDD.fromRDD(inputFiles.rdd(), null);
List<Tuple2<String, String>> localInputFiles = intermediateInputFiles.collect();
```

As you see, localInputFiles has tupples, first element is a filename, second element is the whole content of that file.
I can print every single filename from that collection.
Then I want to sort the list( according to filenames, so I only interested with first element of the tupple) via Collections.sort, but because Tuple2 has no default comparator, I sort it like that:

```
    Collections.sort(localInputFiles, new Comparator<Tuple2<String, String>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Tuple2<String, String> o1, Tuple2<String, String> o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return o1._1().compareTo(o2._1());
        }

    });
```

Tuple2._1() returns a String by the way, so I used String comparison.
After this point, I can't print elements of the localInputFiles list.

What is wrong in this code?

Edit: After sort, I guess spark context closes itself, or something different happens. I couldn't even print "Hello World" after sort. Maybe it crashes because of memory(because in that list, I'm holding contents of the files.) However, Spark UI says jobs finished successfully.

Some explanation: I used sortByKey after wholeTextFiles and it worked of course, but I wonder why I can't sort that list in my driver program.

Comment: can you show errors?

Comment: There is no error at the runtime. I just can't access list elements after sort.

Comment: It doesn't even print result of System.out.println(localInputFiles == null);